# links are always NO-CARRIER, but expected to work

Tags: networking, rhel

At some point I start receiving "NO-CARRIER" error message. What does it mean and how can I fix it? My links are "physically up" - green lights are blinking. On the opposite side link is up, but no traffic. Even no ARP response.

NetworkManager is disabled. If I enabled NetworkManager then I always have "NO-CARRIER" no matter what.

```
[root@localhost ovazhnev]# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:fc:ba:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:fc:ba:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp2s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0f:53:22:79:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp2s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0f:53:22:79:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[root@localhost ovazhnev]# ip link set enp2s0f0 up
[root@localhost ovazhnev]# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:fc:ba:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:fc:ba:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp2s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0f:53:22:79:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp2s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0f:53:22:79:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I think that links are physically ok because:

- NO-CARRIER problem happened right after upgrading to RHEL 7.1 what means that problem likely in software
- after rolling back to RHEL 7.0 NO-CARRIER persist
- NO-CARRIER problem was solved after unplug and plug power cord
- NO-CARRIER problem arise again after installing RHEL 7.1
- NO-CARRIER problem persist after unplug and plug power cord

Finally I don't know what cause "NO-CARRIER problem" but it seems that links are phisically fine because sometimes they work. Also it's unlikely that TWO links at the same time get broken, i'm using LACP.

Comment: Sounds like a driver bug... What hardware (in particular Ethernet chip) is this?

Comment: i'm using Solarflare SFN7122F. second network card functions so this affects only Solarflare card. i've turned off (no power cord unplug) server for ~5 hours, after turning it on network starts function, NO-CARRIER disappear. I suspect either network card or SFP+ transivers. it's important to know if this is software bug or hardware, i.e. should I change my network card and ask to repair it by warranty

Comment: so far it seems turning off server for a small period or time (15-30 minutes) doesn't help, but turning it off for a longer period of time (1+ hours) does help.